# Use purrr to iterate over a vector of values to generate lagged values

Tags: r, loops, functional-programming, tidyverse, purrr

I'd like to use some of the purrr functions to create a vector of lagged values in a column.

I've a dataframe as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = sample(1000, size = 100)
)
```

I can create a new column with the first lagged value as follows:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(y = lag(x, n = 1))
```

I'd like to expand column y to capture lagged values of 1:3 and store them in a numerical vector.

I'm using `map_vec` assuming I'm passing in a vector of values 1:3 and wish to get a vector out

```
df %>% 
  mutate(y = map_vec(.x = 1:3, .f = lag))
```

This errors out saying:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
i In argument: `y = map_vec(.x = 1:3, .f = lag)`.
Caused by error:
! `y` must be size 100 or 1, not 3.
```

Since R is a vectorised language I assumed it would pass 1:3 to lag, then iterate over each value of x.

I can resolve the error by wrapping the map_vec in a list but I get only NA values in the list, it doesn't appear to be passing any lagged values.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(y = list(map_vec(.x = 1:3, .f = lag)))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide a simplified minimal example say with only five values in the x vector and then include your expected output?

Comment: @Peter I've actually created this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76518543/create-a-data-frame-with-lagged-values-as-numeric-vector-using-dplyr but I'm hoping to get a purrr approach so I can pipe it into my existing code. This new question is a pared back version so that I can build up my approach to the end goal.

Comment: This tutorial seems to be very relevant, in showing how to do lags of 1:3 with purrr: https://typethepipe.com/vizs-and-tips/how-to-create-multiple-lags-in-r/

Comment: @JonSpring thanks for pointing me to this blog, this is exactly what I needed. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Jon Spring I was pointed to this blog: https://typethepipe.com/vizs-and-tips/how-to-create-multiple-lags-in-r/

I was then able to add to this function to collapse lagged values into a list:

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = sample(1000, size = 100)
)

calculate_lags <- function(df, var, lags) {
  map_lag <- lags %>% map(~ partial(lag, n = .x))
  return(df %>% mutate(across(.cols = {{ var }}, .fns = map_lag, .names = "{.col}_lag{lags}")) %>% 
           rowwise() %>% 
           mutate(lags = list(c_across(x_lag1:x_lag3))))
}

df %>% 
  calculate_lags(var = x, lags = 1:3)
```